# Negative version of "high spirit"

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, translation

I am looking for a certain noun similar to "High spirits". It carries two pieces of information:

1. The regarded person is in a very happy state, acts this way and knows no danger.
2. It indicates that his actions will result in some bad consequences for him.

Ideally it would fit in the following sentence:

His [noun] lead to his demise.

I looked up a few candidates in the dictionary and I find that they are all flawed in some sense:

Cockiness, high spirits, wantonness, exuberance, devilment.

Might fitting: larkiness, coltishness, friskiness

However I am not sure, since I am not too familiar with any of those. Does there exist one in the English language?

Comment: Stoned? Drunk? High?

Answer (score 3):

These are great adjectives of an attitude that would fit: 'flippant', 'carefree',  or 'cavalier'.

"His cavalier attitude lead to his demise."

This one is my favorite though: 
**insouciance**: lighthearted unconcern

Answer (score 1):

Recklessness, careless, rash and some other synonyms.

What you listed mainly focuses on the cheerful side.

I'd suggest **carelessness** overall.
It results from a lot of things, usually involves happiness, and action obliviousness.

Comment: Carelessness seems more like a symptom, result of the first property, recklessness does not always indicate happiness. It might be better to ask, which noun indicates carelessness. Your answer was definitely helpful.

Comment: +1 *He thought he was carefree, but he was merely careless.* and I think your *obliviousness* is another possibility.

Comment: And we usually answer single word requests with definitions and links to a dictionary reference.

Answer (score 0):

*[Slapdash](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/slapdash)* or *[slipshod](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/slipshod)* may work for you:

> slapdash: done too hurriedly and carelessly.
>
> slipshod: (typically of a person or method of work) characterized by a lack of care, thought, or organization.

[from Oxford Dictionaries Online]

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please remember to cite your sources. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for an overview of our standards and practices.